# Evaluate $\int x\frac{\tan{x}}{\cos^{2}{x}}\,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, integration-by-parts

What is $\int x \frac {\tan{x}} {\cos^{2}{x}}dx$? I managed to get to $\frac {x\sec^2x}2+\int \frac {\sec^2x}2-\frac12+c$ but I'm not sure if I can absorb the $-\frac12$ into the constant at this point. Guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: What is $\cos^2$? Do you mean $\cos^2x$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$ \int x \frac{\tan(x)}{\cos^2(x)} \; dx $$

$$ \int x \tan(x)\sec^2(x) \; dx $$

Do integration by parts with $u=x$ and $dv = \sec^2(x) \tan(x) \; dx$.

Then $du = dx$ and $v = \frac{1}{2} \sec^2(x)$ or $\frac{1}{2} \tan^2(x)$ depending on how you choose to take the antiderivative.  It seems a little easier to choose the former.

Apply the formula for integration by parts to get

$$ \frac{1}{2} x \sec^2(x) - \int \frac{1}{2} \sec^2(x) \; dx$$

$$ \frac{1}{2} x \sec^2(x) - \frac{1}{2} \tan(x) + C$$

Comment: But doesn't $\int \frac12 \tan^2x dx$ = $\frac12 \tan x -\frac x2+c$?

Comment: Yes, it does.  However, if you went that route when you were doing integration by parts, the first part of your answer should be $\frac{x\tan^2(x)}{2}$ instead of $\frac{x\sec^2(x)}{2}$.

Comment: If you choose $v = \frac{1}{2} \tan^2(x)$, then your answer will be $\frac{x\tan^2(x)}{2} -\frac{1}{2} \tan(x) + \frac{x}{2} + C$

Comment: So $ \frac {x \tan^2 x} {2} - \frac12 \tan x + \frac x2 + c = \frac {x \sec^2 x} {2} - \frac12 \tan x + c$?

Comment: Yes.  It follows from the identity $\tan^2(x) = \sec^2(x) -1$.